# How to access Varien object values in observer magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

Hi in my custom module i use the cms_page_save_after event to save some more data with cms pages.While in oberver i got such type of data which i can't process.

```
Varien_Event_Observer Object
(
    [_data:protected] => Array
        (
            [event] => Varien_Event Object
                (
                    [_observers:protected] => Varien_Event_Observer_Collection Object
                        (
                            [_observers:protected] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                    [_data:protected] => Array
                        (
                            [data_object] => Mage_Cms_Model_Page Object
                                (
                                    [_cacheTag:protected] => cms_page
                                    [_eventPrefix:protected] => cms_page
                                    [_eventObject:protected] => object
                                    [_resourceName:protected] => cms/page
                                    [_resource:protected] => 
                                    [_resourceCollectionName:protected] => cms/page_collection
                                    [_dataSaveAllowed:protected] => 1
                                    [_isObjectNew:protected] => 
                                    [_data:protected] => Array
                                        (
                                            [form_key] => 1TVTYLITcZn3dUZm
                                            [page_id] => 3
                                            [title] => About Us
                                            [identifier] => about-magento-demo-store
                                            [stores] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [0] => 1
                                                )

                                            [is_active] => 1
                                            [content_heading] => 
                                            [content] =>
```

I try $observer->getData('page_id') code but don't show anything.Does anyone know how to work with this object.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$observer->getEvent()->getDataObject()->getPageId()
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. But Sorry i also try this method but didn't show anything.

Comment: @MahmoodRehman: My bad, try $observer->getEvent()->getDataObject()->getPageId().